# Oracle Timestamp - date format not recognized

Tags: sql, oracle, date

I have a column in my table which is of type Timestamp.
while converting this field to the format: **2003-08-09T05:48:37+05:30**, I am using the following query:

```
select 
TO_CHAR(CONSUMER_DLY_TIME, 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SSTZH:TZM')
from oms_cust_ord_head;
```

it gives me the error:  "date format not recognized"

How to resolve this ?

Comment: Should work http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9eecb7d/12778/0 Which version do you use?

Comment: Could there be something different in Oracle?
the same doesn't work in 11g.

Comment: How to set that?
this query works fine, but it doesn't pick the table column:

SELECT
TO_CHAR(SYSTIMESTAMP, 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SSTZH:TZM', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=ENGLISH')
FROM oms_cust_ord_head;

Comment: `Timestamp` vs `timestamp with time zone`? You store as `timestamp` where `SYSTIMESTAMP` return `TIMESTAMP with time zone`

Comment: Its just TIMESTAMP(6) datatype.

Comment: Use casting: `select 
TO_CHAR(CAST(CONSUMER_DLY_TIME AS TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE), 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SSTZH:TZM')
from oms_cust_ord_head;`

Comment: You aren't storing a time zone but you want time zone information in your output.  What time zone do you want your string to represent?  Why aren't you storing the time zone with the data?

Answer (score 1):

A `TIMESTAMP` value does not contain any time zone information, thus you cannot display it.

Which time zone do you want do be shown?

For time zone of database operating system you can use:

```
SELECT 
   TO_CHAR(CONSUMER_DLY_TIME, 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS')||TO_CHAR(SYSTIMESTAMP, 'TZH:TZM')
```

or for you current session time zone:

```
SELECT 
   TO_CHAR(CONSUMER_DLY_TIME, 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS')||TO_CHAR(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 'TZH:TZM')

SELECT 
   TO_CHAR(CAST(CONSUMER_DLY_TIME AS TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE), 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SSTZH:TZM')

SELECT 
   TO_CHAR(CONSUMER_DLY_TIME, 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS')||TZ_OFFSET(SESSIONTIMEZONE)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use

```
select trunc(<timestamp_column>) from your_table
```

Read [Format Models](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements004.htm) in detail.

**Note: Format in which the date will be displayed depends on your session parameter nls_date_format.**